# Spring Boot: Unable to configure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

It seems(maybe not) that, SpringBoot is unable to load application.properties file which resides on src/main/resources. What extra config I need to add to boot my app?

**Error Trace:**

Caused by:

> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException:
>   Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type
>   NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on
>   the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a
>   particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are
>   currently active).

**MembersApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MembersApplication {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SpringApplication.run(MembersApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

**DatabaseConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

  @Value("${db.driver}")
  private String DB_DRIVER;

  @Value("${db.password}")
  private String DB_PASSWORD;

  @Value("${db.url}")
  private String DB_URL;

  @Value("${db.username}")
  private String DB_USERNAME;

  @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
  private String HIBERNATE_DIALECT;

  @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
  private String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL;

  @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
  private String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO;

  @Value("${entitymanager.packagesToScan}")
  private String ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_DRIVER);
    dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
    dataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

    return sessionFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = 
        new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing DB JAR on your classpath. If you are using Maven/Gradle, just include JDBC driver dependency into your POM/gradle file.

Comment: when i tried to add http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.37 , maven warned "Duplicating managed version". I guess spring boot has added dependency for me?

Comment: Just remove the version from maven dependency. This is feature of Spring Boot.

Comment: i have added spring jpa and removed, but still facing it