# I can't maven install my empty maven project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to make an api. I want to try to make it with Spring&Hibernate using Intellij Idea and i've never used any of them.

I have succeed to create the Spring project with intellij. But even if the project is 'empty', i haven't changed anything yet, i can't do a maven install it.

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at [...]

    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at [...]

    Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:180)
    at [...]
```

My pom.xml
    
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        4.0.0

```
    <groupId>com.bloombooking.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>bloombookingapi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>bloombookingapi</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Maybe i need some kind of properties somewhere but i don't know which ones and where to put them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem !

So it was that i didn't configure something as you said. I didn't needed to install the jdbc (i don't know why i don't need it) but just to put some properties on the file : /main/ressources/application.properties

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mybase
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=mdp
```

Thx for the answers anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

> You are missing DB JAR on your classpath. If you are using
>   Maven/Gradle, just include JDBC driver dependency into your POM/gradle
>   file.

Taken from here:
[Spring Boot: Unable to configure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982811/spring-boot-unable-to-configure)

As first try to add the dependency to your pom:

```
    <!-- ORACLE database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then if it does not work add it manually with the "mvn install:install-file" goal..

Comment: Ok, so i only need to download the postgresql jdbc jar and put it somewhere in my project ? Where exactly ? (when i try to put it in ressources it won't change anything same error)

Comment: The cleanest way is to install it in your local maven repository and add it as a dependency.  Take a look at http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/

Comment: i suggest to you to install a local maven and enable the command line...      http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_environment_setup.htm               Trust me is really useful..